# Notepad++ Python, space is black

Tags: notepad++

When I use Notepad++ for Python language, my space becomes black, but for other programming languages, it's still ok. Anyone know how to fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjksz.png)

Comment: take a look at settings->style configurator. There choose "Python" from your language list and have a look at the settings for the different styles. Default should be a white background with changing foreground colour, depending on the language component.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's solved

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at `settings->style configurator`. There choose `Python` from your language list and have a look at the settings for the different styles. Default should be a white background with changing foreground colour, depending on the language component.